# Twitter issue with AddThisSdk

Tags: android, addthis

I am trying to share to facebook and twitter using AddThisSdk in android.So far facebook is working fine.But with twitter, i got some issues.When i click on "Authorize app" button in twitter dialogue,i am getting a white blank page and remains there.I have added the following jar files- addthis0.0.7.jar,signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar. and also have configured the library as below

```
Config.configObject().setShouldUseTwitterOAuth(true);
Config.configObject().setTwitterConsumerKey("XXXXXXXXX");
Config.configObject().setTwitterConsumerSecret(
                "XXXXXXXXXX");
Config.configObject().setTwitterCallbackUrl(
                "https://addthis.com/mobilesdk/twittertesting");
Config.configObject().setTwitPicApiKey(
                "XXXXXXXXX");
```

Any help or suggestions in this issue is highly appreciable,
Thanks inadvance